# Press a Button just one time

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to press the first button just one time. This button usually return a random card but I want it just one time. Then the button should be inactive. How can I do that?
That's my code:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    Boolean buttonPressed = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    final Button background = (Button) findViewById(R.id.A);
    Resources res = getResources();
    final TypedArray Deck = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.Deck);
    final Random random = new Random(); 
    if (!buttonPressed){
        buttonPressed = true;
    background.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) { 

            //Genrate a random index in the range
            int randomInt = random.nextInt(Deck.length()-1);
            // Generate the drawableID from the randomInt
            int drawableID = Deck.getResourceId(randomInt, -1);
            background.setBackgroundResource(drawableID);
        }
         });
```

Comment: within the onClick : background.setEnabled(false);
have you tried something like that?

Comment: yes I tried it. It gives me the possibility to press the button one time, but I need to press it only two times

Comment: keep a static counter that counts the number of times clicked. if timesClicked > 1 -> setEnabled(false);

Comment: try, also with a loop but nothing changes

Comment: and why would you have a loop? that makes very little sense. how did you implement it?

Comment: Basically I have tried to insert a loop that gives me the possibility to press the button just two times

Comment: all I see a loop doing, is act as if the button has been pressed twice as soon as you press it once. you don't need a loop here.

Comment: Ok, I have inserted a condition in my code. I have edited it above

Comment: pretty useless change.
have a static counter in your class, default value to 0.
in your onclick:

myCounter += 1;
if ( myCounter > 2 ) break;
// because if this if statement returns true, that code has been executed (at least) two times already

Answer (score 1):

If the player has an action to do next, the simpler way is to deactivate the button when is pressed first time and after in the next action activated again.

You can do this adding

```
background.setEnabled(false);
```

in your anonymous class listener and after add

```
background.setEnabled(true);
```

in player's next action.

Answer (score 1):

you can disable your button with (place it inside your onClick)

```
background.setEnabled(false);
```

and you also might initialize your button to true in onCreate method